# Tag score layout issue

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, localization, russian-stackoverflow

As far as I know there are some modifications in profile page. In particular the [current layout](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/alexolut?tab=profile) for tag score is ugly:

> [image: new]

The old one uses numbers aligned vertically (text is right-aligned):

> [image: old]

Such design issue affects all localized sites. The English version looks better due to same length for "score" and "posts" words, but is also not perfect:

> [image: eng]

Comment: no repro on MSE and english sites using chrome.